# Why is my UnhandledExceptionFilter not being called on a simple divide by zero?

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, visual-c++, unhandled-exception

I am using the following MSVC++ console application code (running on Windows 8.1, Release, Win32) to try and return a top-level exception back to me:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

LONG WINAPI UnhandledExceptionFilter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS exception)
{
    printf("Got an unhandled exception.");
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(UnhandledExceptionFilter);
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = a / b;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

My `UnhandledExceptionFilter` doesn't actually seem to ever get called on the divide by zero exception that is being thrown in this example, otherwise I would expect the "Got an unhandled exception" log message to show up. Why is that?

Comment: I have had a similar name collision between a class name and one buried within the `windows.h` header file.  My solution has been to rename my class slightly to no longer collide with `windows.h` class names.  It has not always been obvious from compiler messages that the `windows.h` content has been used first.

Comment: The example you provided cannot be build successfully, because `UnhandledExceptionFilter` is already defined in `kernel32.lib` when linking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Integer division by zero is undefined behavior. If an implementation choose to raise an exception for that (or for any other undefined behavior), that's fine. If an implementation chooses **not** to raise an exception for some undefined behavior, that's also fine. Whatever the implementation does when confronted with undefined behavior is fine. It's not their problem.

Apparently MSVC++ running on Windows 8.1, Win32 doesn't raise an exception on division by zero.

You should never expect undefined behavior to result in something expected.

Comment: Is there any way to override this behavior in order to catch this?

Comment: There is also a chance that the compiler optimizes out this part of the code - I know it does it for me even with `-O1` (on MinGW)

Comment: @Alexandru - In general, no. It's undefined behavior. The solution to undefined behavior problems is to never invoke them in the first place.

Comment: As I see you are using Windows... Windows supports __try/__except/__finally which can catch these exceptions types. Strongly recommend preventing Div-0 rather than catching it.

Comment: *Strongly recommend preventing Div-0 rather than catching it.* Yep. The same goes for adding the largest possible signed integer to itself, taking the square root of a negative number, or calculating asin(2). Just don't do it.

Comment: Interesting...what are all the different types of unhandled exceptions that the unhandled exception filter catches? Surely there must be a reference to these, right? I just wanna make sure I catch as much as possible in my code. :)

Comment: The reason why I ask this question is more for the purpose of this (interesting read if you guys are curious on how to produce a stack trace on an exception - but I'm still trying to tweak it to work the way I want it to): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487887/why-doesnt-stack-walking-work-properly-when-using-setunhandledexceptionfilter/22489045#22489045

Comment: Answer is correct, but in this case it is @TomerArazy that has diagnosed the OP's problem correctly: in Release builds optimization is on and the variable `c` is unused.  The compiler will omit it and the expression that initializes it - and the two lines above it as well - and the division will not be in the code.  He could try writing `c` to the console: Then it won't be dead and the division will be evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

The function specified by SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() won't be called if the application is running under a debugger, the idea being that SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() should only be used to generate a crash dump and then exit an application. This isn't very useful if you have a debugger attached, so the debugger will handle the exception first.

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) references this:

> After calling this function, if an exception occurs in a process that
>   is not being debugged, and the exception makes it to the unhandled
>   exception filter, that filter will call the exception filter function
>   specified by the lpTopLevelExceptionFilter parameter.

Comment: Note that if you're using something like `ntsd`, `cdb`, or `windbg` from the Debugging Tools for Windows package you can control this with the `sx*` family of commands that control how exceptions will be handled in the debugger.  By default it will break in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

1. as @zhenguoli says, `UnhandledExceptionFilter` is defined in `kernel32.lib` so it will not link. You need to name your exception filter something else. `UnhandledExceptionFilter` is what calls your exception Handler set by `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`.
2. @DavidHammen is unclear because div by zero is indeed handled with exception vector 0 on x86 and `GetExceptionCode()` would return `EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO`. But, as @davidbak says, in the OP's example compiler does not allow this as the variable c isn't used and will be optimised out. If c were used, then the exception handler at vector 0 would start unwinding the stack and eventually call `UnhandledExceptionFilter` as a filter expression which is wrapped around the thread entry function in `RtlUserThreadStart`, which will then call your handler (the thread is started with `RtlUserThreadStart` as the entry function with the real thread entry function as a parameter). The `.exe` entry function will initialise the CRT and then call `main`. You are right to use SEH because divbyzero [can't be caught by C++ exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6121690/7194773), which only responds to `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

Divide By Zero is actually a CPU trap, more than an exception as in programming sense. You should define a trap handler instead of an exception handler.

Comment: So is an Access Violation, but that is reliably caught by Windows Structured Exception Handling

Comment: The exceptions that is defined, as you see divide-by-zero is not included. For details in Microsoft C++ Implementation look here.(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t65b74ad.aspx). GCC implementation is similar.

domain_error Class
invalid_argument Class
length_error Class
logic_error Class
out_of_range Class
overflow_error Class
range_error Class
runtime_error Class
underflow_error Class

Comment: Those are Standard C++ exceptions. I very intentionally wrote [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679356(v=vs.85).aspx). As you see, division by zero is included. Twice even, for floating point and integer types.

Comment: We're talking about Windows programming in this question and the OP is asking about a specific API: `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`. Structured Exception Handling is the game.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the exceptions isn't actually a true unhandled exception from the OS perspective. You're calling `printf`, so you have linked in the CRT. IIRC, the CRT handles exceptions escaping from `main`, but from the OS viewpoint an unhandled exception is one that escapes the true entry point - i.e. the CRT function which calls main.

I believe you actually want a Vectored Exception Handler.